# docker: как стартовать nginx и оставить контейнер работать?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker

Господа,

по неким причинам, котрые выходят за рамки этого вопроса, я собираю свой контейнейр для запуска nginx.

Начал я с простого. я написал Dockerfile

```
    FROM ubuntu:18.04
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
    EXPOSE 80 443
```

и после `docker build -t my_nginx .`
получил образ. Чтобы контейнер не завершился сразу после запуска, я запускал его командой `docker run --name nginx_1 -p 1080:80 -d my_nginx sh -c "sleep infinity"`

Но... так как в контейнере никто не нписал команду `service nginx start` - то nginx был остановлен. Если я заходил в контейнер командой `docker exec` и вручную запускал его - все работало, но это как то неправильно.

Чего я после этого только не пробовал делать

И так:

```
    FROM ubuntu:18.04
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
    EXPOSE 80 443
    RUN service nginx start
```

И так:

```
    FROM ubuntu:18.04
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
    EXPOSE 80 443
    CMD service nginx start
```

-не помогает.

Я даже пытался вкоманду `service nginx start` в sh - файл, закинуть его в контейнейр командой COPY и выполнить, но всё равно - контейнейр запускаается, а сервис nginx в нём остановлен.

Как бы эту проблему решить? Хорошо бы еще и от уродливого  `sh -c "sleep infinity"` в конце команды docker run избавиться, если у кого то уже есть опыт.

Спасибо за советы заранее!

PS. И не могли бы Вы в нескольких словах объяснить, почему те два способа запуска (последне команды в приведенных мной Dockerfile), котрые я попробовал, не срабатывают?

**Дополнение**

Через несколько месяцев после первоначальногов опроса и любезного ответа Sergei Kirjanov я вернулся к своей проблеме с запуском контейнера... И обнаружил, что в прошлый раз мне не хватило всего одной команды, чтобы nginx остался работать при  запуске контейнера - так, как я хочу!

В общем, `Dockerfile` выглядит так:

```
    FROM ubuntu:18.04
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
    EXPOSE 80 443
    STOPSIGNAL SIGQUIT
    CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

Как видите, команде, котрую мне посоветовал Сергей, должна была предшествовать строка `STOPSIGNAL SIGQUIT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`service` не нужен. В нашем случае сервисом для ОС является сам докер-демон.

`RUN` работает на этапе сборки образа.

Нужно `CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]`.

Как я узнал? Сделал `docker pull nginx`, `docker history nginx --no-trunc` -- история сборки официального образа.

---

Вместо этого `daemon off;` можно писать и в конфиг самого nginx.

Без `daemon off;` процесс запуска nginx будет сразу возвращать управление запускаючему (докеру), и он решит, что контейнер отработал.

`["` нужны, чтоб не делать лишний шелл процесс.

---

Например:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx-test
    ports:
    - "127.0.0.9:80:80"
    - "127.0.0.9:443:443"
version: '2'
```

```
docker build -t nginx-test .
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Лучше добавьте эти полезные пояснения отредактировав ответ, а не в комментах ([подробности](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419/198251)).

Comment: Ширкарно! @Sergei Kirjanov - cпасибо большое, Вы ответили даже на тот вопрос, который меня мучил, и на который я не находил простого ответа: как посмотреть внутрь готового докер - образа.

Comment: Уважаемый @Sergei Kirjanov, я попробовал добавить команду CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"] в конец своего докер - файла (который есть в вопросе). Но... видимо, магия работает только в руках настоящих волшебников. nginx по прежнему не стартует. И контейнер стразу же завершает работу.

Comment: @S.H., добавил подробней. Можно еще посмотреть, что у вас `docker logs ...` говорит

Answer (score 1):

Была такая же проблема, решил так:

1. Создаем bash файл например с названием "init.sh":

   #!/bin/sh

   service nginx start

   #тут еще любые команды, например запуск php-fpm

   bash
2. В dockerfile пишем

COPY init.sh init.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "init.sh"]

3. Запускаем контейнер

docker run -it -d <image_name>

и проверяем, должен запуститься "неумирающий" контейнер с запущенным nginx внутри.

Comment: Красота. Спасибо! Хотя, со времени, когда я задал вопрос, я уже вроде как научился это делать - этот изящный рецепт еще пригодится,!