# Как быстрее запускать Docker?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

У меня есть `docker-compose` для запуска скриптов на различных языках программирования:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  python_runner:
    build:
       context: compilers/python  # путь до Dockerfile
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
       - ./temp:/temp   # текущая директория будет видна в /temp
    container_name: python_runner_container
    environment:
      - FILENAME=${FILENAME}

  cpp_runner:
    build:
      context: compilers/cpp  # путь до Dockerfile
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./temp:/temp   # текущая директория будет видна в /temp
    container_name: cpp_runner_container
    environment:
      - FILENAME=${FILENAME}
...
```

С сайта приходит код и язык, на котором он написан. Затем я создаю временный файл и из питона, при помощи библиотеки subprocess, выполняю команду:

```
docker run -i -v {self.current_path}/temp:/temp --rm --env FILENAME={filename} {compiler}
```

Переменные **current_path**, **filename** и **compiler** создаются заранее.

Код, присланный пользователем должен пройти тесты, по этому фактически я выполняю одну и ту же команду порядка 15 - 20 раз с различными stdin. В среднем выполнение одной команды занимает 1.8 - 2 сек, при том что сам код выполняется буквально за 0.006 сек.

Как мне ускорить этот процесс?

Comment: А как насчет того, чтобы всё время держать запущенным контейнер, и в нём - бегущим процес, который смотрит на отмапленный в FS хоста фолдер. Вы кладёте в фолдер файл, котрый надо подать на stdin - и уже запущенный контейнер выполняет код, подав ему этот файл на вход. Тогда задержка будт минимальной. А, забыл добавить: так как у Вас контейнер получается параметризован переменными current_path, filename и compiler - то придётся на каждую новую комбинацию создавать свой экземпляр контейнера - можно имя контейнера комбинировать из этих переменных.

Comment: @S.H. а как держать контейнер запущенным, и каким образ я могу отдать ему команду, что надо запустить такой-то файл с такими-то входными данными?

Comment: Держать запущенным - есть много способов, один из них мне подсказали вот здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174043/. А "отдать команду" - пусть он мониторит директорию на появление в ней новых файлов? Я даже готов попробовать соорудить proof of concept, но для этого было бы хорошо дополнить Ваш пример примером кода и парой примеров тестов.Кроме того,возникает еще одна проблема (не зависящая от реализации): а что,если на каком то из тестов код зациклится и контейнер повиснет? Фактически, нужен внешний "монитор", который "отстреливает" контейнер,если тест не отработал слишком долго.

Comment: Вообще, то, что я предлагаю - это некоторое нарушение принципо докера: вот в Вашей системе есть код, он запускается в контейнере, и на его вход подаётся тест. А потом тот же код, опять в контейнере, и другой тест. При этом у кода гарантированно нет "состояния": контейнер для каждого теста создаётся заново. Я же предлагаю на каждый код на вход подавать все тесты, друг за другом. Это быстрее, но начинает зависеть от состояния,а также,требует модификации кода - нужно ему добавить "внешнюю обёртку", котрая засовывает в него каждый тест. Так что надо десять раз подумать, идти ли на такое усложнение

Comment: @S.H. Скрипт, который запускает docker контейнер: https://pastebin.com/zwhD9HgK
Скрипт, отвечающий за прохождение тестов: https://pastebin.com/RhArT5fN. На данный момент код конечно не идеален, но я буду дорабатывать его

Comment: По-моему, тут все эти сложности (с мониторингом директории, мониторингом процесса и т.д) не нужны. Если задержка действительно вызвана запуском контейнера, то запустите его один раз (хотя бы скрипт, который в цикле спит, что-то типа `bash -c "while true; do sleep 1; done"`), а потом просто выполняйте в контейнере команды через `docker exec`. Директорию, конечно, нужно заранее при запуске (docker run) подключить, а перед  `docker exec` туда подкладывать файлы.

Comment: Но это только более простой способ переиспользовать контейнер. Гораздо лучше понять, почему медленно работает. `сам код выполняется буквально за 0.006 сек` это вы измеряли внутри докера? Или это без докера так?

Comment: @Roman Konoval это время взятое из результата работы команы time, например, в Dockerfile, который запускает python код эта строчка выглядит так: `CMD bash -c "time python temp/${FILENAME}`. А в .env файле значение переменной TIMEFORMAT="%3R"

Comment: Вы неправильно используете докер. Неправильно запускать вашу команду на фазе создания образа (т.е. из Dockerfile). Создайте образ один раз, а потом используйте его для запуска с разными входными параметрами. Что сейчас у вас входит в 2 секунды, от которых вы пробуете избавиться - не совсем ясно, но судя по всему туда входит и создание образа, и это главная проблема.

Comment: @RomanKonoval - спасибо, замечание насчет docker exec - абсолютно верное, как мне самому это не пришло в голову! Автору вопроса: тут Роман предложил гораздо лучший вариант, чем у меня, и вообще - говорит очень правильные вещи.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, можете написать свой комментарий как ответ и я отмечу его как решение

Comment: @RomanKonoval, Здравствуйте, это снова я. Я переписал свой код так, что теперь контейнер для запуска скрипта на каком-нибудь языке программирования создается один раз и в дальнейшем я просто запускаю нужный мне файл через команду `exec`. Вот пример такой команды: `docker exec -i python_container bash -c "time python temp/tmp9vk8ci3r.py" 2>&1`, однако, время выполнения одной такой команды все равно значительно превышает время выполнения скрипта (время выполнения команды ~ 1 сек, а время выполнения скрипта ~ 0.025 сек)

Comment: P.S. контейнер создается командой: `docker run -it -d --name cpp_container -v C:\Users\Владелец\PycharmProjects\CompilerS\docker\temp:/temp compilers_cpp_runner bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно используете докер в этом случае, а именно, неправильно запускать вашу команду на фазе создания образа (т.е. из Dockerfile).

Создайте образ один раз, а потом используйте его для запуска с разными входными параметрами. Что сейчас у вас входит в 2 секунды, от которых вы пробуете избавиться - не совсем ясно, но судя по вашем комментариям туда входит и создание образа, и это главная проблема.