# Почему Docker контейнер не видит файл?

Tags: c++, bash, docker, файловая-система, dockerfile

[Мой предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1368148/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-docker) (косвенно связан с этим)

Я создаю контейнер:

```
docker run -it -d --name cpp_container -v (путь до папки)\temp:/temp compilers_cpp_runner bash
```

Далее запускаю команду:

```
docker exec -i cpp_container g++ -o TempCPP /temp/hello_world.cpp && bash -c "time app/TempCPP" 2>&1
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
/bin/bash: app/TempCPP: No such file or directory
```

Хотя, если зайти в контейнер и посмотреть на структуру файлов, то фидно, что в папке **/app** все таки есть файл **TempCPP**:

```
root@bc13219a8729:/app# ls
Dockerfile  TempCPP  temp_cpp  test1.cpp
```

Даже в PyCharm'е говориться что этот файл там есть:

[image: Скриншот из PyCharm]

Dockerfile выглядит следующим образом:

```
FROM gcc:latest
WORKDIR /app
```

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Эта команда выполняется не в докере

Comment: А где? И как выполнять эту команду в докере?

Comment: `&&` обрабатывает sh из которого вы запускаете эту команду. Т.е. он сначала выполняет docker exec, а потом сам запускает bash -c. См. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416286/how-to-run-2-commands-with-docker-exec

Comment: `$ docker exec -i cpp_container bash -c "(g++ -o TempCPP /temp/hello_world.cpp && time ./TempCPP) 2>&1"`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin можете переписать свой комментарий в ответ, и я отчему его как решение