# Как сделать чтобы контейнеры не останавливались после запуска?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

Запускаю 3 контейнера с помощью docker-compose, но т.к. контейнеры запускаются без служб, после старта они автоматически останавливаются с кодом 0. Как сделать чтобы они не останавливались?

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    server_a:
        image: ubuntu:20.04
        container_name: server_a_ubuntu

    server_b:
        image: ubuntu:20.04
        container_name: server_b_ubuntu

    server_c:
        image: ubuntu:20.04
        container_name: server_c_ubuntu
```

Comment: Это похоже на проблему XY. ¿Для чего нужны 3 контейнера с базовой убунтой? Они же ничего не делают.

Comment: Тестовая работа, далее на в этих контейнерах будут работать скрипты для установки различных пакетов. Грубо говоря, использую docker-compose вместо вагранта.

Comment: Создавайте образ с нужными пакетами и приложениями и запускайте контейнер используя его.

Comment: К сожалению, по ТЗ система должна быть без предустановленных пакетов.

Comment: Не поможет ли Вам вот такой вопрос--ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174043/ Правда, там я всё делал через докерфайл...

Comment: Значит на самом деле проблема XY. Рассказывайте, что вы пытаетесь делать на самом деле.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему добавлением `command: tail -f /dev/null`